# ORACLE using decode

Tags: oracle

I need to list all undo tablespace names in an Oracle (19c) database (regardless of whether they're used or not) from the `ts$` table.

My SQL statement below gives that info but it also lists all the tablespace types (which I don't want). If I refine the statement to exclude the types and return just the list of UNDO tablespace name(s) is DECODE the core T function to use?

```
select name,
       decode(ts.contents$, 0,(decode(bitand(ts.flags, 4503599627370512), 16, 'UNDO',4503599627370496, 'LOST WRITE PROTECTION','PERMANENT')), 1, 'TEMPORARY') 
from ts$ ts ;
```

Is there a better alternative to this function? (Like CASE)

Comment: Found a related post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3193692/case-vs-decode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you only want rows where `bitand(ts.flags, 4503599627370512)` = 16. No decode/case needed.

```
select * from ts$ ts
where  ts.contents$ = 0
and    bitand(ts.flags, 4503599627370512) = 16;
```

Comment: Brilliant. That's exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The following works. Maybe there's a better way to write this though. Perhaps decode shouldn't be used.

```
set feedback off
set heading off

select name from ts$ ts
        where decode(ts.contents$, 0,(decode(bitand(ts.flags, 4503599627370512), 16, 'UNDO',4503599627370496, 'LOST WRITE PROTECTION','PERMANENT')), 1, 'TEMPORARY')='UNDO' ;
```